# MySQL, I want to change the value of another table with the largest value

Tags: mysql

There are two tables

```
A
ENO | VALUE |  YMD
 1  |   3   | 190308   
 1  |   10  | 190309
 1  |   5   | 190310 

B
ENO | TARGET | 
 1  |   10   |
```

We want to update the TARGET column of table B to the most recent date with the value "VALUE".

I want to change the result of the B table as follows.

```
B
ENO | TARGET |
 1  |    5   |

What should I do?
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to do this? It seems like redundancy.

Comment: @Strawberry The deadline is imminent, but there are too many places to use the TARGET column of table B above. So I will add the A table as a temporary fix, and later I will delete the B table and consolidate it into the A table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below -

```
update tableB A 
join 
(select * from tableA x where ymd in (select max(ymd) from tableA x1 where x.eno=x1.eno)
)B on A.eno=B.eno
set A.target=B.target
```